# Winforms application stops drawing but remains reactive to events

Tags: c#, winforms

We have a C# .NET 3.5 UI client application that runs in a multiple monitor desktop environment (typically 4 screens) on Windows 7.  Every so often, after running several of these applications, the screen stops redrawing.

Controls continue to be reactive to clicks or keypress and values can be updated programmatically, but the entire form is not redrawn to reflect any changes.  For example buttons that are enabled/disabled based on state may be remain grayed out, but be reactive to clicks or vice versa.  Buttons do not animate when clicked.

Workaround: minimizing and restoring the window appears to clear the problem.  After this, the application begins to draw correctly.

The must frustrating aspect of this problem is that programmatically, everything appears to be running normally.  No exceptions are caught in our logs.  Nothing was visible in the system event logs.  We have not found a way to detect this condition is happening yet.

Other miscellaneous aspects: logging uses log4net, server communication layer uses ZMQ

**Update:**
Calling form Invalidate() and Update() does not fix the problem.
When dragging the window between screens, it shows different values on each screen.
Minimize/restore still resolves the issue.

Comment: Does the UI refresh if you do a manual Invalidate()?

Comment: We added a button that causes form Invalidate() and Update() but that did not fix the problem.  He was able to minimize/restore to recover.

Answer (score 0):

I can't be sure of anything without seeing the app and the code, but my best guess is someone calls `.SuspendLayout()` before a complicated update, and an exception (probably swallowed) prevents the code from ever reaching the corresponding `.ResumeLayout()`. To test this, try adding a button that calls `.ResumeLayout()` for the form.

Comment: It took a bit to reproduce after adding ResumeLayout, but it did not have an effect.  The fact that the display shows two distinct but frozen UI 'snapshots' when dragging the window between two monitors leads me to believe it is either a Windows 7 or display driver problem.  As before, minimizing and restoring the window appears to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the solution is there:
1) http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alejacma/archive/2009/08/11/controls-won-t-get-resized-once-the-nesting-hierarchy-of-windows-exceeds-a-certain-depth-x64.aspx
2) http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2664641/en-us